# jquery $.post - sending a string of 7KB - results in 403 error

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to send html of a page to server - to check something
but - getting error in console

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var str = document.documentElement.innerHTML;  // doesn't work
    //changing to var str = 'lorem'; - this works 
    console.log(typeof(str)); // string
    console.log(str); // works in both cases
    $.post('check.php', {ht: str}, function(data){  // error line
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**check.php**

```
$str = $_POST['ht'];
echo $str;
```

**console**

`POST https://example.com/check.php 403`
the entire html as text is about 7 KB
so what is wrong with sending html (as string)

Comment: Have you checked the log files on the server? Have you verified it happens for HTML data only - and about the same amount of "non-HTML" data would go through? If the latter, then you probably have something running on the server, that rejects such requests that contain HTML, assuming that it _might_ be an attempt to hack the system and make use of an XSS vulnerability or something.

Comment: *The `HTTP 403 Forbidden` client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. This status is similar to `401`, but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.* This sugersts that your PHP Script does not have the correct permissions to allow the Web Server to display it. Check your permissions on the server.

Comment: @CBroe - just tested with a `lorem` string of 13kb - it works. Server log files are ok. Is there a way to encode the html string - so it can go to server - and decode it once it is there ?

Comment: @Twisty - 403 is in console, but obviously - this is not the problem, everything works with a `lorem ipsum...` string of 13 kb

Comment: Idk, base64 would probably be your easiest option for that. (But then you still got to hope, that whatever checks for this on the server side, isn't smart enough to recognize it nevertheless.)

Comment: Before you go down this path of sending the entire HTML of the page to the server, what exactly are you needing to 'check'? I'm almost certain there will be a *much* better approach you can use instead.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I need to validate the html, because it is composed on a dinamic way. And it is much easier for me to do it in php comparing to js. For example - to check  if each open `div` or `p` tag is closed

Comment: But why do you need to send this from the client to the server for that kind of purpose? I doubt that it is HTML dynamically created _on the client_ (when you trigger your functionality directly on window load) - so why don't you make an HTTP request in PHP to get the source code from a URL?

Comment: @CBroe - on server side I have some source html but mainly there are php functions to build content on various html parts

Comment: @qadenza why not use cURL then?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zu074t8x/

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">Hello World!</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var ht = $("body").prop("outerHTML");
  console.log("Sending", ht);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/html/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      html: ht
    },
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Getting", results);
    }
  });
});
```

This will get the Document Body element and create a String of the Outer HTML elements.

It may be good to Encode it, yet it should send as a String just fine. You might want to adjust the Selector to `$("html")` or `$(dopcument)` as needed.

I see the following in the Cosnole:

Sending

```
<body>
    <div id="foo">Hello World!</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[


$(function() {
  var ht = $("body").prop("outerHTML");
  console.log("Sending", ht);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/html/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      html: ht
    },
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Getting", results);
    }
  });
});



  //]]></script>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: ""
      }], "*")
    }

    // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
    window.name = "result"
  </script>




</body>
```

Getting

```
<body>
    <div id="foo">Hello World!</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[


$(function() {
  var ht = $("body").prop("outerHTML");
  console.log("Sending", ht);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/html/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      html: ht
    },
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Getting", results);
    }
  });
});



  //]]></script>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: ""
      }], "*")
    }

    // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
    window.name = "result"
  </script>




</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue some days ago, the solution was encode the string with javascript function encodeURI()

`var text = encodeURI("<div>test</div><b>testing</b>");`

And then in php you decode it with

`$html = urldecode($_POST['ht']);`

Comment: doesn't work, try with entire document, not just a div